# What is a "mule farm" in uwsgi?

Tags: uwsgi

What is a "mule farm" in uwsgi and what can it be used for? Are there some usage examples? I have not found anything in the docs or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a named group of mules

> --farm chickens:1,2,3. --farm cows:4,5.

creates 2 farms: "chickens" with mules 1, 2, 3 inside and "cows" with mules 4, 5 (this is mule's id)

you can register signal to specific farms via *uwsgi.register_signal(x, "farm_chickens", handler)*, and then only mules in farm 'chickens' will recieve signal *x*

Also you can send and recieve messages via farms
*uwsgi.mule_msg("message", "farmname");*

Comment: Can I connect to database in mule?